# Ansible + LXC (Proxmox)

Tags: ansible, lxc, proxmox

Problem: to create the LXC (Proxmox) in ansible playbook.

Playbook:

```
- name: Create LXC
  proxmox:
    node: PVE-03
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: password
    api_host: 192.168.254.23
    password: 11111
    hostname: ans
    ostemplate: data:vztmpl/debian-9.0-standard_9.5-1_amd64.tar.gz
```

Log:

```
fatal: [192.168.254.23]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "authorization on proxmox cluster failed with exception: Couldn't authenticate user: ********@pam to https://192.168.254.23:8006/api2/json/access/ticket"}
```

Comment: Have you created that user and provided the necessary rights?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to update a proxmox:

```
apt full-upgrade
```